# VBA code in multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm relatively new to using VBA. I have this code that reads a set of data in a range and concatenates the data into once cell. I have a vast range of cells that this code needs to be ran on. Could someone help me with looping it, so when the code has finished for one range, it moves down the next cell and starts on the next range?

```
Sub ConcatenateAll()
    Dim x As String, y As String, rng As Range, cell As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range("AT1:CB20")
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                x = x & cell.Value & "; "
            End If
        Next
        .Range("AK1").Value = Left(x, Len(x) - 2)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the order in which the range is traversed matter? Also, what do you mean by "when the code has finished for one **range**"? Are there other ranges besides `.Range("AT1:CB20")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I can think of it is to pass parameters to the `ConcatenateAll` procedure and then mention what all ranges you want to concatenate. For example, I am calling the `ConcatenateAll()` twice from `Sample()`

I also took the liberty to slightly modify your code.

```
Sub Sample()
    With ActiveSheet
        ConcatenateAll .Range("AT1:CB20"), .Range("AK1")
        ConcatenateAll .Range("AT31:CB50"), .Range("AK2")
    End With
End Sub

Sub ConcatenateAll(rngInput As Range, rngOutput As Range)
    Dim x As String, cell As Range

    For Each cell In rngInput
        If Len(Trim(cell.Value)) <> 0 Then
            If x = "" Then
                x = cell.Value
            Else
                x = x & "; " & cell.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next

    rngOutput.Value = x
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

> AT1:CB20, AT21:CB40, AT41:CB60, AT61:CB80 I would like the result displayed in AK1, AK2, AK3, AK4 and so on until the end of the ranges – user2668126 4 mins ago

Try this code. Since there is a trend, it becomes easier to loop through the ranges.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long, i As Long

    r2 = 20: i = 1

    With ActiveSheet
        For r1 = 1 To 2001 Step 20
            ConcatenateAll .Range("AT" & r1 & ":CB" & r2), .Range("AK" & i)
            r2 = r2 + 20: i = i + 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Sub ConcatenateAll(rngInput As Range, rngOutput As Range)
    Dim x As String, cell As Range

    For Each cell In rngInput
        If Len(Trim(cell.Value)) <> 0 Then
            If x = "" Then
                x = cell.Value
            Else
                x = x & "; " & cell.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next

    rngOutput.Value = x
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I wanted. However, I have around 2000 ranges to use this in. Is there a way I can create a simple function to run through all of those and display the appropriate data?

Comment: If there is a trend in the way the ranges are placed then you can call all those ranges in a loop. If you can give few examples of your ranges then I can see if there is a trend... For example `AT1:CB20`, `AT31:CB50`, `AT61:CB80` Here we can see the trend...

Comment: There is a repetition in the ranges, each one is as you used in an example. The final range is AT2001:CB2020

Comment: Can you give me an example of first 4 ranges? Like I gave an example above for 3 ranges. Also mention output cells that you want the output in..

Comment: AT1:CB20, AT21:CB40, AT41:CB60, AT61:CB80
I would like the result displayed in AK1, AK2, AK3, AK4 and so on until the end of the ranges

Comment: See the `FOLLOWUP` in the updated pot. You might have to refresh the page :)

Comment: THANK YOU! This works perfectly! You've saved me an awful lot of time and headaches! Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to display the output in a cell, I think that the best way to act is to write a custom VBA function and then use it as an Excel worksheet function
To do that, first you need to define a public function on a VBA module:

```
Public Function concat(values As Variant)

   Dim val As Variant, aux As String

   For Each val In values
       If val <> "" Then aux = aux & val & "; "
   Next val

   If Len(aux) > 2 Then aux = Left(aux, Len(aux) - 2)
   concat = aux

End Function
```

Then you can use this function as an worksheet function, e.g. you can write in the  cell `AK1` `=concat(AT1:CB20)` and you will get the same result of your code

Comment: This could be useful as I will probably need to use the code again at some point. However, when I did as you instructed and type the formula in, an error occurs in the cell. Any ideas?